# Azure Local Web Role "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-roles

I have this Azure Web 2.3 project working on a Windows 7 machine, but for some reason on a totally new Windows 10 machine when I run the azure project, i get a blank white screen that 500s with the phrase:

`The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.`

This is the response for all MVC3 endpoints and for all static html files in the web project.

Other facts:

- the WebRole.cs `OnStart()` gets called
- the Global.asax.cs `Application_Start()` gets called
- the Global.asax.cs `Application_Error()` gets called when the site first boots up due to not having a controller mapped to `/`-- so it handles at least this request,,, a bit
- the Global.asax.cs `BeginRequest()` and `EndRequest` functions gets called. For all requests when i inspect `HttpContext.Current.Response` it says that the response is a 200 OK, although in chrome i'm getting a 500 server error...
- i've checked the local azure compute emulator and it says that i'm using the correct host and port (which makes sense, given that the app is def semi-handling requests as described above)

Totally lost on this one. Windows 10 thing?

Comment: This might help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/05/remote-debugging-a-window-azure-web-site-with-visual-studio-2013.aspx

Comment: Wait... to be clear, when you are inspecting the HttpContext.Current.Response object, and that shows 200 OK... is that on the windows 10 machine? If so, it must be related to the networking on the local machine and is not related to your code... like a firewall traffic or port rule specific to that machine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after updating to Azure 2.7 from 2.5. The solution I found here worked for me: http://www.thedailyparker.com/post/2014/06/07/aa5142ff-846a-4764-9a22-a390c79a2578

They stated that after hours of debugging they found a misconfig in the azure diagnostics trace listener. Removing the section did the trick for me (although my version seemed to be configured correctly). Maybe my emulator wasn't updated correctly or something.